# adding a value to a form input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that has several inputs with the same name:

```
<div data-payment-option="credit-card">
    <input type="radio" name="payment-option" value="credit-card">

    <input type="radio" name="credit-card" value="mastercard">
    <input type="radio" name="credit-card" value="visa">
</div>
<div data-payment-option="paypal">
    <input type="radio" name="payment-option" value="paypal">
</div>
<div data-payment-option="wetransfer">
    <input type="radio" name="payment-option" value="wetransfer">
</div>
```

my question is:
when the form submits, i want to override `form['credit-card'] = 'paypal'` if the radio 'payment-option' has 'paypal' selected; same for 'wetransfer'. I want to do it on submit because if the payment-option is 'credit-card' i want to keep 'mastercard' or 'visa' as selected.

I have tried:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(ev){
    form['credit-card'] = 'paypal'
    // and
    $('input[name=credit-card]').val('paypal')
})
```

but when i log the value of the input i get undefined

Comment: sorry, i updated my answe

Comment: You can change the `value` of an input, but why? The values you will post will depend on which inputs are `checked`

Comment: why do you need to do this? Is the server-side reading the wrong field to determine the payment option? Surely if "payment-option" = "paypal" then it would just ignore the "credit-card" field? Anyway you can't use .val() to set a radio button field. You must use the "checked" property of the radio you want to be selected, and since you're trying to set it to a value that doesn't exist, that won't work either. I'd say this is an X Y problem, and the server-side needs fixing to use the submitted data in a sane way.

Comment: @ADyson have you ever worked in a big company? unfortunately "changing the backend" is not always the most practical - or at least fast enough - solution, even though the best.

Comment: @AndFisher, if you look closely, that is not what i asked

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez I think it is unclear exactly what you are asking.

Comment: thank you for your effort, but i don't think it's unclear

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez I've only ever worked in big organisations, but I've always been able to get the back-end changed if there's a valid reason. It sounds like the logic in it is not very good. I take it you / your team is not responsible for the back-end code in this case, or that there is a lot of other code which already depends on it working in this strange way?

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez what would be the result if you submitted nothing at all for the "credit-card" field when the payment option is "paypal"? If you disable all the credit-card radios whenever the payment option != "credit-card" then they won't be submitted at all. Disabling the field would be much easier than trying to alter the value after submission.

Comment: @ADyson, both guesses are correct, in a perfect shit-storm. Thing is the functionality must go live today, and our backend dev can't touch this till next week at least plus, this is so messy that it has the possibility to break a lot of stuff when the backend is touched

Comment: @ADyson, i have a quick question for you? is my question clear enough? AndFisher doesn't think so

Comment: Why not append a new input on submit? `<input type="radio" name="credit-card" value="paypal">` and programatically set it to checked?

Comment: I think the question is quite clear, yes. Clearer than very many on this site!

Comment: Another potential quick-and-dirty option for you is to use a proxy field. So have a hidden field named "credit-card". And change your current credit-card radio buttons to have another name (e.g. cc-proxy). Handle the change event of the payment-option radios, and depending on the selected option, you can enable/disable the cc-proxy radios. If payment-option != creditcard, set the "credit-card" hidden field to be the same as payment-option. If not, use the value of cc-proxy. Also handle the change event of cc-proxy and update the value of the credit-card hidden field to match.

Comment: @AndFisher then you'd have multiple different elements with the same "name" attribute. Sounds like a recipe for confusion. Unless you remove the existing credit-card radio buttons at the same time. Then it might work. But in any post-submit scenario you run the risk that the page is submitted before the script finishes running, could be flakey. You'd need to prevent-default and then retrigger the submit from script as well.

Comment: @ADyson the only elements with the same name would be credit card, as you'd expect for radio options. Presumably this is the desired effect?

Comment: @AndFisher yes but it could conflict with any option already selected in the radio button (entirely possible if user has changed their mind). It wouldn't remove that selection simply by creating another element with the same name. Not sure how the browser would serialize the post data in that scenario either. It might ignore the later addition, I can't remember. Safer to stop the submission, remove/disable the other fields, then re-submit.

Comment: @ADyson I think that's the point, some logic needs to go into the onsubmit so that it only sets the paypal value if a user has checked the Paypal payment option from the other radio group. That is missing from the example.

Comment: @AndFisher yes it does, that's exactly the point, and your suggestion is one way to achieve it, but I was just pointing out it might need refining a little.

Comment: @AndFisher thank you for your answer, you got what i was asking for. your first suggestion is the approach i wanted to avoid but apparently it is what i'm going to do... i just think there should be a way to do this. Thank you both :)

Comment: as i need to ship this in 2 hours, i will go with AndFisher's first suggestion, of the two radio buttons, with the same name. @AndFisher if you can post that as an answer, there's 10points waiting for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: (https://jsfiddle.net/k44n0ak0/)

```
$('form').on('submit', function(ev){
    if($('input[name="payment-option"]:checked').val() === 'paypal') {
        var $pp = $('<input type="radio" name="credit-card" value="paypal">');
        $pp.prop('checked', true);
        $(this).append($pp);
    }
})
```